# Partitioned external hard drive: where are my files?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, external-hdd

I recently upgraded my laptop hard drive and did a fresh install of 12.04.3.  I stuck my old hard drive into an external enclosure to use as an external - but first, I need to get all my data off it.  The old hard drive was dual boot with Win7 and Ubuntu...here is the output of sudo fdisk -l:

[image]

So, sdb is obviously the external.  However, I've tried mounting all 3 of those partitions - sdb1, sdb2 and sdb3, and none of them seem to be my old ubuntu partition.  sdb2 is my Win7 partition (which is nice), sdb1 is my Win7 recovery partition (useless) and I'm not sure what sdb3 is (it has folders like "BIN", "BOOT", "IMAGES_BOOT", "PLANFOLDER", and so forth.

Any ideas on where to find my ubuntu partition?  As a last resort, I can re-install the old hard drive, dump everything I need off the ubuntu partition onto another external, reinstall the new hard drive, and carry on.

Thanks!

Comment: This wasn't a wubi install by any chance?  The whole Ubuntu installation would then be in a file on the Windows partition.

Comment: @ubfan1 Yep, this was it - I thought I had done a separate install, turns out I was using WUBI this whole time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have originally done a [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) installation, in which case Linux was installed to a file in the Windows filesystem (normally `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`). I'm not sure of the format of this file, but if it's a simple image file, you should be able to mount it as a loopback device. For instance, if you mount your former Windows `C:` partition at `/mnt/windows`, you could try:

```
sudo mount -o loop /mnt/windows/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /mnt/oldubuntu
```

(You will have to have created both the `/mnt/windows` and `/mnt/oldubuntu` directories before doing this.)

Comment: I did a WUBI install at first before deciding to go with a full install, but I'm pretty sure I made a separate partition for the actual install.  I'll try this, however.

Comment: Aha! I never did a full install, this whole time I've been running off the WUBI install.  Thanks a bunch!